# Wrap the whole word in a span element if the word includes combination of specific letters

Tags: javascript

i have code below which finds and wraps those words in a span element, but only them.
i would like to wrap a whole word if it inludes those words. for example: GSHAA or GSH112

my code:

```
var words = ["GSHT","GSH","SHV"];

$('.list-icons a').html(function(_,html) {
    var reg = new RegExp('('+words.join('|')+')','gi');
    return html.replace(reg, '<span class="wrap">$1</span>', html)
});
```

Comment: remove that `$1`, as not everyone understands PHP syntax in that case

Comment: @FlashThunder in a js regex replace operation `$1` gets replaced by the first capture group and so is not PHP. I understand the confusion though as that syntax is pretty much forever imprinted into my brain as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your regular expression to match the entire word instead of only the substring, you should check for the *word boundary* using `\b`. See this solution:

```js
var words = ["a", "b", "c"];

// To prevent errors when looking for words with special characters
const escapeRegex = (str) => str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

$('.list-icons a').html(function(_, html) {
  const query = words.map(escapeRegex).join('|');
  const regex = new RegExp(`(\\b\\w*(?:${query})\\w*\\b)`, 'gi');
  return html.replace(regex, '<span class="wrap">$1</span>')
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: black;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-icons">
  <li><a>Apple pie ice</a></li>
  <li><a>Blueberry cake</a></li>
  <li><a>Honey</a></li>
</ul>
```

Simplified, `(\\b\\w*word\\w*\\b)` means "*look for a string that begins with a word boundary (a space or a newline), then your `word` followed and preceded by any amount of alphanumeric characters (`\w*`) and ends with a word boundary again*".

Because you are inserting your words into a regular expression, you should escape them so that special characters (like $ . and +) do not cause regex parsing errors. I took and modified `escapeRegex` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript/3561711).

Answer (score -1):

according to the docs, you must return the changed value of the HTML not to use the HTML replace function

```js
var words = ["GSHT","GSH","SHV"];

console.log($('.list-icons a')[0]);

$('.list-icons a').html(function(_,tag) {
    var reg = new RegExp('('+words.join('|')+')','gi');
    if(reg.test(tag)){
      return `<span class="wrap">${tag}</span>`
    }
});

console.log($('.list-icons a span')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-icons">
  <li><a>GSHAA</a></li>
   <li><a>a</a></li>
  <li><a>a</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: did you even check your not working code? do you really think that op expects `$1` as output, by saying "wrap"?